# Error installing angular-cli using node v4.6.0 npm 3.10.8 on windows 8

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I am getting below errors in log file and don't know how to resolve.
Could someone help please ? Thanks in advance.

```
Registry url: https://registry.npmjs.org/
Current Time: 10/09/2016 10:34:35
Last Refreshed: 10/09/2016 10:05:59
Number of Results: 363330
====Executing command 'npm install angular-cli -g '====

npm WARN addRemoteGit Error: Command failed: git -c core.longpaths=true config --get remote.origin.url

npm WARN addRemoteGit 

npm WARN addRemoteGit     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:213:12)

npm WARN addRemoteGit     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)

npm WARN addRemoteGit     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)

npm WARN addRemoteGit     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:829:16)

npm WARN addRemoteGit     at Socket.<anonymous> 
(internal/child_process.js:319:11)

npm WARN addRemoteGit     at emitOne (events.js:77:13)

npm WARN addRemoteGit     at Socket.emit (events.js:169:7)

npm WARN addRemoteGit     at Pipe._onclose (net.js:486:12)

npm WARN addRemoteGit  webpack/compression-webpack-

plugin#7e55907cd54a2e91b96d25a660acc6a2a6453f54 resetting remote 

C:\Users\Ali\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-webpack-compression-webpack-plugin-git-7e55907cd54a2e91b96d25a660acc6a2a6453f54-ec76b2fe because of error: { [Error: Command failed: git -c core.longpaths=true config --

get remote.origin.url

npm WARN addRemoteGit ]

npm WARN addRemoteGit   killed: false,

npm WARN addRemoteGit   code: 1,

npm WARN addRemoteGit   signal: null,

npm WARN addRemoteGit   cmd: 'git -c core.longpaths=true config --get 
remote.origin.url' }

npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\Ali\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-
remotes\_templates --mirror git@github.com:webpack/compression-webpack-plugin.git C:\Users\Ali\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-webpack-compression-webpack-plugin-git-7e55907cd54a2e91b96d25a660acc6a2a6453f54-e286d0b5: Cloning into bare repository 'C:\Users\Ali\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-webpack-compression-webpack-plugin-git-7e55907cd54a2e91b96d25a660acc6a2a6453f54-e286d0b5'...

npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\Ali\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror git@github.com:webpack/compression-webpack-plugin.git C:\Users\Ali\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-webpack-compression-webpack-plugin-git-7e55907cd54a2e91b96d25a660acc6a2a6453f54-e286d0b5: Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '192.30.253.113' to the list of known hosts.

npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\Ali\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror git@github.com:webpack/compression-webpack-plugin.git C:\Users\Ali\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-webpack-compression-webpack-plugin-git-7e55907cd54a2e91b96d25a660acc6a2a6453f54-e286d0b5: Permission denied (publickey).

npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\Ali\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror git@github.com:webpack/compression-webpack-plugin.git C:\Users\Ali\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-webpack-compression-webpack-plugin-git-7e55907cd54a2e91b96d25a660acc6a2a6453f54-e286d0b5: fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\Ali\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror git@github.com:webpack/compression-webpack-plugin.git C:\Users\Ali\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-webpack-compression-webpack-plugin-git-7e55907cd54a2e91b96d25a660acc6a2a6453f54-e286d0b5: 

npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\Ali\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror git@github.com:webpack/compression-webpack-plugin.git C:\Users\Ali\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-webpack-compression-webpack-plugin-git-7e55907cd54a2e91b96d25a660acc6a2a6453f54-e286d0b5: Please make sure you have the correct access rights

npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\Ali\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror git@github.com:webpack/compression-webpack-plugin.git C:\Users\Ali\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-webpack-compression-webpack-plugin-git-7e55907cd54a2e91b96d25a660acc6a2a6453f54-e286d0b5: and the repository exists.

npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.2.9200

npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Ali\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "angular-cli" "-g"

npm ERR! node v4.6.0

npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8

npm ERR! code 128

npm ERR! Command failed: git -c core.longpaths=true clone --template=C:\Users\Ali\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror git@github.com:webpack/compression-webpack-plugin.git C:\Users\Ali\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-webpack-compression-webpack-plugin-git-7e55907cd54a2e91b96d25a660acc6a2a6453f54-e286d0b5

npm ERR! Cloning into bare repository 'C:\Users\Ali\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-webpack-compression-webpack-plugin-git-7e55907cd54a2e91b96d25a660acc6a2a6453f54-e286d0b5'...
npm ERR! Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '192.30.253.113' to the list of known hosts.

npm ERR! Permission denied (publickey).

npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

npm ERR! 

npm ERR! Please make sure you have the correct access rights

npm ERR! and the repository exists.

npm ERR! 

npm ERR! 

npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:

npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:

npm ERR!     F:\Project_TypeScript\A2Vs\NodeA2\NodeA2\npm-debug.log

====npm command completed with exit code 1====
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you run command-line as administrator?

Comment: yes i did. I even used powershell in administrator mode.